# Can I override a system function before calling fork?

Tags: linux

I'd like to be able to intercept filenames with a certain prefix from any of my child processes that I launch.  This would be names like "pipe://pipe_name".  I think wrapping the open() system call would be a good way to do this for my application, but I'd like to do it *without* having to compile a separate shared library and hooking it with the LD_PRELOAD trick (or using FUSE and having to have a mounted directory)

I'll be forking the processes myself, is there a way to redirect open() to my own function before forking and have it persist in the child after an exec()?

Edit: The thought behind this is that I want to implement multi-reader pipes by having an intermediate process tee() the data from one pipe into all the others.  I'd *like* this to be transparent to my child processes, so that they can take a filename and open() it, and, if it's a pipe, I'll return the file descriptor for it, while if it's a normal file, I'll just pass that to the regular open() function.  Any alternative way to do this that makes it transparent to the child processes would interesting to hear.  I'd like to not have to compile a separate library that has to be pre-linked though.

Comment: Do you have control over the process you exec? Meaning is it your code?

Comment: In theory, yes, but I'd like a solution that works for any binary...

Comment: I don't think that's possible without the LD_PRELOAD trick. Using it should work fine.

Comment: That's my thought too, I'd really like to avoid having to build a separate library though.  I'm trying to build a header-only library.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the answer here is no, it's not possible.  To my knowledge, there's only three ways to achieve this:

1. LD_PRELOAD trick, compile a .so that's pre-loaded to override the system call
2. Implement a FUSE filesystem and pass a path into it to the client program, intercept calls.
3. Use PTRACE to intercept system calls, and fix them up as needed.

2 and 3 will be very slow as they'll have to intercept every I/O call and swap *back* to user space to handle it.  Probably 500% slower than normal. 1 requires building and maintaining an external shared library to link in.

For my application, where I'm just wanting to be able to pass in a path to a pipe, I realized I can open both ends in my process (via pipe()), then go grab the path to the read end in /proc//fd and pass *that* path to the client program, which gives me everything I need I think.